# Loading the new action creates strange error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to create a login system.  My UserController has this to control the `new` action:

```
def new
    @user = User.new

    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => @user }
        format.html
    end
end
```

and my routes.rb has this to link:

```
resources :user
```

The View's form to create a new user is this:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
```

however, I receive an Action Controller error with this:

```
undefined method `users_path' for #<#<Class
```

What has baffled me is why it is using `users_path`.  This is a plural reference to my route.   Why is it returning a plural error of `user_path`??  When I route `resources :users' it clears the error, but of course I don't have anything setup for that resource and thus produces other errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resources :users` is actually the correct structure, since it is a collection of users, not a single user. The route construction also expects a plural path (IIRC, it expects a plural path unless it finds a `resource`, as opposed to `resources` route), hence the attempt to use `users_path`.

Passing an explicit url parameter is another option `<%= form_for @user, :url =>  user_path do |f| %>`, since you already have things expecting singular routes

Answer (score 2):

Inside `form_for` it creates an appropriate action and method based on whether or not the model is persisted.

If a model is unpersisted it will create an action of `:new` and method of `:post`. If it is persisted then it will be `:update` and `:put` instead.

For `:new` the default url is '/users' and for `:edit` it's '/users/:id'.

The fix is as Jim said. (Beat me to it.) Apply a url option to `form_for`.